# changing color of different spans one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, settimeout

I have some text and I want it to change color in a manner such that the left alphabet changes color first, then the next one and so on(like a wave). So, I assigned each alphabet a span(with class span0, span1 and so on) and tried changing the color using following code:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
       window.setTimeout(function(){
          $(".span"+i).animate({'color':'orange'}, 400);
    }, 300);
};
```

The code doesn't work. (and I am using the jQuery color plugin)
So, how can I achieve the effect?

Comment: You could [try this](http://jsbin.com/eguvaj/2) in JsBin. **Btw** remember to accept an answer if that answer worked for you!

Comment: @balexandre How can I make that wave run infintely? Whenever I try to do that the browser becomes unresponsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for( var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++ ){
    $( '.span' + i ).delay( 300 + i*50 ).animate( {'color':'orange'}, 400 );
}
```

Using jQuery, delay for an increasing amount of time then animate the color switch.  You have two issues -- You're firing all the animations at the same time, and as Alnitak points out -- your `i` variable isn't in the proper scope

And you can also remove the need for `.span0`, `.span1`, etc by giving them all a `span` class and changing the selector in the above code to:

```
var $spans = $( '.span' )
for( ... ){
    $spans.eq( i )...
```

Comment: good solution using `.delay()` given that it's a jQuery animation effect, but fails to explain why the original didn't work.  I'll +1 yours if you +1 mine ;-)

Comment: are you sure about that new last bit?  It'll change every span on the page, regardless of whether they're the ones the OP wants changing.

Comment: "dot span", everything with "class span", not all "span tags" -- the OP is already adding a class of "span#" to a bunch of things

Comment: ah, yes - although `.eq(i)` would be preferable to a concatenated string.

Comment: actually, I see he already has a `spans` array, so the digit suffixes were never necessary.

Comment: hehe, you're making the assumption that it's an array of nodes and not `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`  :D

Comment: One more thing: Isn't the delay doing the same thing as setTimeout()? Is there some difference?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same as `setTimeout`, though you need to wrap the `i` var in a new scope as in Alnitak's answer if you use `setTimeout` otherwise it gets lost

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic "using a loop variable inside a callback bug" - by the time the callback is invoked the value of `i` is set to its last known value instead of the value it had at the time the callback was registered.

Try this:

```
// _returns_ a new function that's bound to the specified selector
function setcolor(sel) {
     return function() {
         $(sel).animate({'color', 'orange'}, 400);
     }
}

// set the callback to the function returned above
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; ++i) {
  window.setTimeout(setcolor('.spans' + i), 300 + 400 * i);
}
```

per @cwolves answer - you also need to stagger the timeouts otherwise they'll all fire at once, hence the `300 + 400 * i` in the code above.

Comment: @Alnitak Nothing happens to the text. (I can't show it on JSfiddle or something like that because I can't include the colors plugin there)

Comment: @Jatin if the plugin is accessible via HTTP you can include it as an external JS resource.  In any event, just try a one-off `$('.span0').animate(...)` without the timeout - it's probably the plugin that's not working as expected.